# Getting the error "Sampler error: unexpected frame type." when reading a frame using Single Read Sampler with JMeter and JMeter Websocket Plugin

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter for the load testing of an application which includes web socket connection.

When trying to read the data in a frame using Single Read Sampler, got an error  "Sampler error: unexpected frame type."

Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

Comment: There should be an error message in the jmeter.log, indicating which (unexpected) type of frame was received. If it's a ping, than the solution given by Ubik Load Pack is indeed the right way to solve it.

Comment: Also, the "Response message" in the sampler result should read something like "Received: Ping frame with no application data"....

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you use last version of this plugin:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers

You can install it using JMeter Plugin manager:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/

And add a "ping frame filter" as described here:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues/8/error-in-websocket-request-response

Comment: I'm trying to read response from the web socket connection to a signalr hub server. I have tried writing text using single write sampler and it reaches the server but when I try to read a message, error is thrown at response timeout (which is quite high ~ 3 mints).I have already put ping filter since before I had error thrown of wrong type.The text message I am trying to read is a broadcast from server to all connected clients, so I can see that the message has been received by the browser clients but the jmeter client is not getting it.
Please let me know if you need any more clarifications